# How to understand browser location is block or allowd?

Tags: javascript, jquery, location

Both of *Google Chrome* and *Fire Fox* has setting for permission,

- *Google Chrome* has security connection setting. you can see this setting when press the **(i)** button at the beginning of the address bar ( *for https websites click on green lock at the beginning of the address bar* ), then you can see *location* , *camera* and etc.
- *Fire Fox* has security connection setting too. you must press **Alt+T+i** , press permission tab and see *Access your Location* , *Load Images* and etc.

**Now my question**: how I can understand browser location is block or allow with JavaScript or jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

When getting the location, you provide an error callback.  If getting the location is successful you will have it, if they decline then you will not.  I do not believe there is a way to know advance.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: I used `!navigator.geolocation` , but it always returns `false` , even geolocation is **Allow**

Comment: It's returning false because navigator.geolocation exists and ! gives the opposite, which would be false.

Comment: Dear `@Joshua` , I know that what ! means, `navigator.geolocation` is `null` object. Even geolocation is  **Allow**

Comment: if navigator.geolocation does not exist then the feature is not available. To quote mozilla: "If the object exists, geolocation services are available."  So there is something wrong in the browser side of things. I would try in a new incognito window and look into your security settings.